# How to register a event handler to the event of another class in constructor of MainPage.xaml.cs

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8

Situation:

- i have a MainViewModel class that contains a collection named
  “Problems” of type ItemViewModel class
- i have a loadData function in    MainviewModel class where
  ItemViewModel class is instantiated and    instances are added to
  Problems collection .
- i also have a public event Event1 that fires at the end of LoadData
  function.

Doubt :

I want to register the Event1 in constructor of MainPage.xaml.cs , so that it points to a eventhandler defined in MainPage.xaml.cs. How do it do it ?

Following is the code snippet from MainViewModel class , certain declarations have been skipped for sake of clarity

```
    public event EventDelegate Event1;
    public void LoadData()
    {
    //place RT  data here

        this.Problems.Add(new ItemViewModel() { ID = 0, ProblemName = "Fever"});
        this.Problems.Add(new ItemViewModel(){ID=1,ProblemName="Diarrhea"});
        this.Problems.Add(new ItemViewModel() { ID=2,ProblemName = "sprain" });
        this.Problems.Add(new ItemViewModel() { ID = 3, ProblemName = "bruise" });

        OnEvent1();
    }

   protected virtual void OnEvent1()
   {
       EventDelegate handler = Event1;
       if (handler!=null)
       {
           handler();
       }
   }
```

Comment: What is wrong with `mainViewModel.Event1 += EventHandler;` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have set the `DataContext` of `MainPage` to `MainViewModel`, so get the instance and hook your event in constructor after `InitializeComponent()`

```
public MainPage()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   ......
   ((MainViewModel)DataContext).Event1 += HandlerName;
   ......
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

For comments:

> We are wiring the event handler and event1 , shouldn't we write
>   ((MainViewModel)DataContext).Event1 += new HandlerName.

No, you don't need to. Anyhow, you code won't work, have to use delegate name i.e.

```
((MainViewModel)DataContext).Event1 += new EventDelegate(HandlerName);
```

One stated earlier and one stated above are equivalent.

> Second will the statement DataContext = App.ViewModel.MainViewModel;
>   placed after InitializeComponent(); set the datacontext to
>   MainViewModel.

Yeah it will, you can place it before or after `InitializeComponent()` and it will work.

Comment: I have 2 doubts : first . We are wiring the event handler and event1 , shouldn't we write ((MainViewModel)DataContext).Event1 += new HandlerName; and Second will the statement DataContext = App.ViewModel.MainViewModel; placed after InitializeComponent(); set the datacontext to MainViewModel